# Force windows to reconnect to WLAN

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, router

Not sure if this is really a problem of Windows or more some kind of timeout issue.

I have a router where my laptop connects to via WLAN which is on the base floor. Now when I go up to the second floor, there was no WLAN because it didn't reach far enough, so I put a repeater on the first floor.

Often this works, and I have a connection on the second floor. But it happens rather frequently that Windows says it can not connect, even though it shows at least two or three bars on the WLAN icon. As often as not, it even looses the connection completely so that Windows claims it can not find any WLAN at all even though it was connected for some short period.

I noticed that this is happening not so often when I switch off my laptop for an extended period like i.e. one hour or more. When I go up to the second floor then, and only there switch back on, chances are much better that it finds the WLAN now.

So I wonder, is it possible that Windows remembers the device it connected to (either the router, or the repeater) and tries to prefer to reconnect to the same device instead of the one with the strongest signal of the same network? I could imagine that I receive a pretty weak signal from the basement and was asking myself if this might interfere in such a case. If this is the case, can I do something about it to enforce a better connection?

Strangely I noticed that I also have the reverse effect. SO when I get down in the morning, and switch on the laptop it can not connect even in places where the signal should be strong. I have to go in the same room with the router, so that it can "see" it, and only then it it reconnects. After that I can go back to the other room and everyting works fine, so it's only the initial connect that is the problem.

Comment: Typically setting the repeater to the same SSID so,merely as an extender, is what works best and have the easiest usage because any device that connected once to the router would seemingly connect to the strongest signal. But with Windows and certain WiFi chipsets weird things happen... Try setting the repeater as AP instead (different SSID) and test if you can always connect to the better signal (repeater) AP. It may need manual selection of one and other networks.

Comment: People rarely use the term WLAN anymore.  Using this term will confuse people that might otherwise be able to help.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas, so what should I use instead?

Comment: WiFi :)  WLAN is what we called it "back in the day".  Perhaps someone will disagree with me.. I am wrong A LOT. :|